# NodeJS app error during deploy to heroku app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I am trying to deploy my project to herokuapp, but I got some errors:

```js
2018-07-27T08:27:30.827410+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=ihealth99.herokuapp.com request_id=54687736-9467-4484-93d6-b2f016548ce2 fwd="140.213.36.56" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-27T08:27:30.828380+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ihealth99.herokuapp.com request_id=56351cf4-d736-4688-957b-8430d136a3b5 fwd="140.213.36.56" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-27T08:27:33.083646+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ihealth99.herokuapp.com request_id=0558bd4d-42aa-48c5-9c37-05dd43a9e1b9 fwd="140.213.36.56" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Anyone knows whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  console.log("app is up and running");
});
```

heroku deployed server port is not fixed.

Comment: anyway this is my server port `app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){`
  `console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);`
`});`

Comment: Find the error logs in heroku logs --tail and double check about the database connection issue. or try port instead of PORT.

Comment: i tried using port but doesnt make any change.. whats the right syntax to connect to database using mongoose?